# How to disable print option for particular user

Tags: permissions, printing, irm

I have a folder in the Document library.

It has been shared with two group of users(after breaking inherit permissions).

I wanted first group to able  to print the documents but **not the second group**. I understand that, I can disable print option using IRM.

But it disabling at complete folder level.

So, when the first group member login, they are unable to print as IRM disabled it. How to achieve it for selective group members?

Please help.

Comment: So, did it work user85801??

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://www.cloudfronts.com/restrict-download-and-print-option-for-sharepoint-online-document-library/) seems to cover what you require, it involves IRM which you have tagged your question with.

Otherwise, perhaps creating a custom Permissions group would work?  Although I didn't find a [permission level relating to 'Printing' for SP 2013-2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels) - this post doesn't seem to apply to Sharepoint Online.